# Gparted see NTFS windows partition as fat32

Tags: linux, partition, windows, disk, gparted

I'm stuck in linux installation process.

I've resized windows partition in order to be able to install linux (dualboot).

Here is a screenshot of computer manager tool : 
[image: disks on Windows]

Once, I've boot it on live usb, gparted tell me wrong information : there is only one partition witch takes the whole disk.

Here is the screenshot of gparted (from live usb) :

[image]

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you by advance for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like your USB disk you use to boot Linux. I assume there is a third drive in drop-down.

In the livecd, do the following in the terminal (you can leave gparted open):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It should spit out three drives, two that are around 120Gb and one 1Tb drive ...

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem, that way others will see that this answers the question, you do not have to upvote it but it would be appreciated ... note that this has happened to me as well ... I forgot that I had another USB stick in the back of my tower ;-) A sign low caffeine level ...

Answer (score 2):

I found why gparted can't see my SSD! I just changed bios configuration (Stata controller Mode) Intel RST Premium > AHCI.

Now, I see all my disks in gpart.

Now my trouble are arround windows He can't boot anymore with this "AHCI" selected option :-(

Comment: Fixed ! Here is the link witch worked for me : https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15006-attn-ssd-owners-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-10-installation.html